# simd code to check if two double values are sufficiently different

Tags: c++, simd, absolute-value

Suppose I have two double values, old and new.
I would like to implement a vectorized function
that returns old if abs(x-y) < p, and new otherwise.

Here is the code (test.cpp):

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <iostream>

#define ARRAY_LENGTH 2

int main(void) {
    // x = old value, y = new value, res = result
    double *x, *y, *res;
    posix_memalign((void **)&x, 16, sizeof(double) * ARRAY_LENGTH);
    posix_memalign((void **)&y, 16, sizeof(double) * ARRAY_LENGTH);
    posix_memalign((void **)&res, 16, sizeof(double) * ARRAY_LENGTH);

    double p = 1e-4; // precision
    __m128d sp = _mm_set1_pd(p);
    x[0] = 1.5; y[0] = 1.50011; // x - old value, y - new value
    x[1] = 2.; y[1] = 2.0000001;

    __m128d sx = _mm_load_pd(x);
    __m128d sy = _mm_load_pd(y);

    // sign mask to compute fabs()
    __m128d sign_mask = _mm_set1_pd(-0.);
    // |x-y|
    __m128d absval = _mm_andnot_pd(sign_mask, _mm_sub_pd(sx, sy) );
    // mask of |x-y| < p
    __m128d mask = _mm_cmplt_pd(absval, sp);
    // sres = |x-y| < p ? x : y;
    __m128d sres = _mm_or_pd(
            _mm_and_pd(mask, sx), _mm_andnot_pd(mask, sy) );
    _mm_store_pd(res, sres);
    std::cerr << "res=" << res[0] << "," << res[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To build:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -msse4 test.cpp
```

We first compute fabs(x-y), compare to p, and combine x, y using the
obtained mask.

Does anyone see a more efficient way to code this?  Thanks.

Comment: You could try using `BLENDVPD` (`_mm_blendv_pd`) and see if you get better performance.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I didn't know about this instruction.

Comment: @ElderBug: blendv instruction usually translates into 3 uops, so I guess it won't be faster in sense of throughput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to make this algoritm a little faster, but it can decrease accuracy:

```
// d = x - y;
__m128d diff = _mm_sub_pd(sx, sy);
// mask of |y - x| < p
__m128d mask = _mm_cmplt_pd(_mm_andnot_pd(sign_mask, diff), sp);
// sres = y + (|y - x| < p) ? (x - y) : 0;
__m128d sres = _mm_add_pd(sy, _mm_and_pd(mask, diff));
```

Another way - using of AVX or/and single precision.